# XCode 9.1 - Location simulation went missing

Tags: location, simulation, xcode9.1

I just updated my XCode to 9.1 today, and surprisingly I can't find "Allow location simulation" in scheme setting, please refer to the screenshot below:

[image]

Has any one got the same problem? And any suggestion that I can fix it?

Apple's getting worse and worse lately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried restarting XCode and running/stopping the app several times, then the checkbox magically appeared. 
I've also fired a radar to Apple anyway.

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue as well and the fix was to run the application in the Simulator and then go to Edit Scheme while the Simulator was running and the Core Location option magically reappears.

Comment: this helped, I had to toggle the default location to a different city also